# Passing compiler arguments to C plugin in IntelliJ

Tags: c, intellij-idea

I am trying to compile some OpenGL code in IntelliJ using the C/C++ plugin.

Normally I would just run the command:

```
gcc opengltest.c -o opengltest -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

But I can not find a way to add it to the configuration.

I can find where to pass the executable arguments, but not the compiler ones.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you use this plugin: [JetBrains Plugin Repository :: C/C++](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373)?

Comment: @Danek Yup, that's the one

Comment: If I were you, I would have sent a mail with a question about where to pass executable variables to support@adv-tools.com, which is mentioned on the plugin page. There is an obvious lack of documentation for that plugin.